# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5 eventhough I have installed pickle5

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, conda, pickle

I am running a python 3.7 conda environment and I have imported pickle5 into my code however I am still getting the following error regardless:

C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\Bowls App Object Detection>python obj.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Generating anchor boxes for training images and annotation...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "obj.py", line 7, in 
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["white bowls, black bowls, yellow bowls"], batch_size=4, num_experiments=100, train_from_pretrained_model="pretrained-yolov3.h5")
File "C:\Users\Joel\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\Custom_*init*_.py", line 171, in setTrainConfig
self.__train_cache_file, self.__model_labels)
File "C:\Users\Joel\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\Custom\gen_anchors.py", line 82, in generateAnchors
model_labels
File "C:\Users\Joel\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\Custom\voc.py", line 9, in parse_voc_annotation
cache = pickle.load(handle)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

It would be great if someone could help out!